# Can I check parameters of the action method from within my OnActionExecuting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following action:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string city, string street) {
```

Is it possible for me to get the values of the city and street parameters from inside of an OnActionExecuting filter?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you basically want access to your route values here (as opposed to parameter values in a method which you don't have direct access since that is already a 'bound' method - it essentially is the same thing though)

Access your ControllerContext in the method and that gives you access to RouteValues
so filterContext.Controller.RouteValues

[ActionExecutingContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.aspx)

[ControllerContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.aspx)

*EDIT*
For completeness (based on your other post) this data is available if you want just the action parameters 
    string city = filterContext.ActionParameters["city"];

this depends though on what you want to access as ther may be other route parameters not bound to parameter values.

Comment: I always thought we get the current executed action's RouteValues from filterContext.Controller.RouteValues inside OnActionExecuting. I should give it a try.